# Is there a way to make the audio louder on Windows XP using software?

Tags: logitech-speakers

I bought the Logitech zCinema, and the loudest volume on it is not too terribly loud.

The problem is it seems is that the volume on half way is barely audible at all.

Is there a way to exceed the sliders volume in Windows to sort of pre amp the volume? Is there a key in the registry to do this?

I'd rather have the volume at halfway a respectable level.

Comment: Remember that if you amplify the sound via software the audio quality tends to degrade... Software solutions are never always completely reliable (think of how bad photos look if you use digital zoom as opposed to optical zoom on a camera).

Answer (score 2):

Last time when I had a notebook that had a really soft volume, I used a software called AC97MIX where I can control and boost the volume gain system-wide. It might not support your audio card though, so YMMV.

Also, if your audio is a Realtek audio, try downloading the drivers from their official website. It comes with a control panel utility (Realtek Audio Utility) that allows you to increase gain.

[image]

Finally, make sure you plugged the zCinema into the speakers output on your computer, and not the line-out. The line-out output is not amplified, whereas the speaker output is.

Comment: the zCinema connects via USB - and it's volume changer syncs with the Windows volume slider.

Comment: Oh! just found out more about the zCinema - reviews are complaining it's very not very loud too. Return and get a normal set of speaker. :)

Comment: @scoopdreams I bought it off eBay about a year ago!

Comment: @alex dude, sell if off eBay again. :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of is that your audio drivers could have something to do with the softness.  On an XP machine at my office, I was barely getting the sound loud enough to hear my music until I had to wipe and re-install the drivers for causing conflicts with some of my software.  After that, the speakers worked perfectly and I had to turn the volume down a long ways or blast my ears out :)

Not always the case, but something to think about and/or try.